# Header in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying the below script to make a header but its not working and this is very urgent if anyone could help me.

```
\documentclass[conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{215.9mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-9.7mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{184.3mm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{6.3mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0mm}

\setlength{\paperheight}{279.4mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-7.4mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{235.2mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{12.4mm}

\setlength{\parindent}{1pc}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0pt}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{NOT FOR DISTRIBUTION}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I removed the code that was not essential to the question:

```
\documentclass[conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{NOT FOR DISTRIBUTION}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wants the page containing the title information to also have the header, one has to redefine the page style `IEEEtitlepagestyle` issued by `\maketitle`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}

\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{NOT FOR DISTRIBUTION}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{The Title}
\author{Michael Shell \and Homer Simpson}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that with these settings, no page number will be shown; perhaps you could also add something like

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

or something similar to display the page numbers.

Not related to the question, but notice that you are loading the same package more than once (e.g., `amsmath`, `graphicx`); this is not necessary and is a probable cause of clash if some option is passed in the wrong place; load each package just once. Also notice that the caption package and the `IEEtran` class might not cooperate well.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, I've used this four lines but not working \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{NOT FOR DISTRIBUTION}

Comment: @user1460166 Notice that you also have to change some lengths (the lines beginning with `\setlength` in my code). As the image in my answer shows, my code works. Saying simply "not working" is useless. Please edit your question with a simple document like the one in my answer and illustrating that the proposed solution is not working.

Comment: @user1460166 I've updated my answer adding code to add the header also to the page containing the title declaration.

Comment: could you please check my other question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118939/add-watermark-that-overlays-the-images

Comment: @user1460166 I was in bed so I couldn't answer before, but now that I'm awake, I've provided an answer to your other question.