# Add watermark that overlays the images

Tags: watermark, draftwatermark

I want to put a draft watermark using the below script but the problem is that the watermark don't come over the images and I want it to come over it.

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkScale{1}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `\SetWatermarkLightness{0}`?

Comment: Note that images in PDFs are stored in their original form and the watermark is just placed on top of it by the PDF viewer. As long the PDF is not encrypted the original images can be extracted using a PDF editing tool.

Comment: The problem is that the watermark is displayed on the text but not the images

Comment: As Martin said, there might be problems when your images are in `.pdf` format. What kind of images are you dealing with? Can you add some more details in your question?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The problem is that the `draftwatermark` places the material in the background, so other elements (for example, figures and listings) might cover the included material; to prevent this, instead of using the `draftwatermark` package, you can use the [`xwatermark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark) package; the starred variant of `\newwatermark` places the material in the foreground which seems to be what you need. A little example:

First, with the unstarred variant (material on the background, so a figure will be placed on top of it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And now, with the starred variant (material on the foreground, so it will appear on top of figures):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newwatermark*[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the foreground watermark tranparent, so that it doesn't render the text illegible?

Comment: @SFAB please open a follow-up question with this requirement.

Comment: Done, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132582/8277.

Comment: Only difference is the star between the examples? `\SetWatermarkText{P.s. Page limit 25...}`. I used this watermarking [here](http://texblog.org/2012/02/17/watermarks-draft-review-approved-confidential/) with `\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}` but this technique did not work with the packages. You don't use any extra package?!

Comment: I got an error with `\newwatermark`: `! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>X ...=60,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}`

Comment: And is there any way to get ***transparency*** for the foreground watermark?

Comment: To change transparency, I just changed the number at color=red!50

Comment: s.k. - in your example the =60 is a transparency value. Change this number - lower this value to increase transparency.

Comment: xwatermark stopped working in some recent latex version (I'm using the latest TinyTex), looking in the community it seems related to the catoptions package

Comment: I really like the package `xwatermark` but the sad news is, that there is no development in the package and I think it needs to be adopted to recent LaTeX Versions. I'll try to contact the author of the package.