# Transparent foreground watermark

Tags: beamer, graphics, transparency, watermark, xwatermark

As a follow-up to [Add watermark that overlays the images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118939/8277), I'd like to have a transparent foreground watermark that doesn't render the underlying content, i.e. text and images, illegible. Is that possible?

I'm especially interested in using that on a couple of beamer slides in which I'd like to put a semi-transparent watermark/banner above a couple of pictures.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use TikZ to place the watermark inside a `\node` and then use the `opacity` key:

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\tikz[color=red,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}
\newwatermark*[
  allpages,
  angle=45,
  scale=6,
  xpos=-20,
  ypos=15
]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[4]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for that solution!

Comment: Maybe @AhmedMusa could have a look at that, too, and add it as an option within the xwatermark package?

Comment: @ GonzaloMedina is there a way to do this while using `polyglossia`? Right now it is not compiling.

Answer (score 7):

While I like the simplicity of the `tikz` solution, here's a `pstricks` solution.  This solution does not allow you to automatically create a watermark for each page.  But, it does allow you to place a personalized watermark in the foreground for a given page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%% called for `scalebox`
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% `pstricks` packages needed.  Also, need `\SpecialCoor` to parse post
%% script commands fed to `\rput` for the angle.
\usepackage{pst-abspos,pst-text}
\SpecialCoor
%% Instead of using `\scalebox` as I have below, you could define your
%% own font to be used for the watermark.  But the approach I've taken here
%% is a bit more flexible if you intend to use multiple and different watermarks
%% throughout your document which you may want scaled differently.
\DeclareFixedFont{\WM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{3cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\createWatermarkOrigin}{\pstSetPostScriptOrigin}
%% this is use to adjust where `pstricks` places the absolute coordinates.  
%% In other documentclasses, this is 1in from the top, and 1in from the left edge of the
%% paper.  In beamer, the setting seems to come out differently.
\def\centercorrection{1.30in}
%% #1 -> content of watermark
%% #2 -> magnification for watermark
\newcommand{\addWatermark}[2][10]{%%
  \pstPutAbs(\dimexpr0.5\paperwidth-\centercorrection\relax,
            -\dimexpr0.5\paperheight-\centercorrection\relax)%%
            {\rput{! \number\paperheight\space \number\paperwidth\space atan }
                  (0,0)%%'
                  {\pscharpath[linestyle=none,opacity=0.5,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red]
                              {\scalebox{#1}{#2}}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\createWatermarkOrigin
  \lipsum[4]

  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.75in]{example-image-a}

  \addWatermark{Draft}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a two step process.  When you open the `beamer` `frame` you must call `\createWatermarkOrigin`.  This macro creates a coordinate system for the beamer frame.  I've had to do a bit of tweaking because the usual reference point is shifted (see comments in the MWE for more details).

After setting up the coordinate system,  you may call `\addWatermark` which takes an optional argument for scaling, and a mandatory argument for the content of the watermark.

Answer (score 6):

With a current latex version, you could use the `shipout/foreground` hook to add a watermark:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[red,rotate=30,scale=10,opacity=0.2] at (current page.center) {Draft}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]