# Stickers on Thesis paper

Tags: graphics, formatting, book-design, watermark

I want to  put a  sticker "Examiners Copy" on the the front page of the thesis. How to do this?

Comment: You mean on the title page? Where on the page you want it? And what should be the rotation of the text of sticker?

Comment: First page , I mean besides the Thesis title. And any good design is no problem.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/transparent-foreground-watermark, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118939/add-watermark-that-overlays-the-images

Comment: If that is literally what you plan to put on the very first page of your thesis, I very strongly advise you not to. It will not make a good impression to emblazon a basic grammatical error all over your title page. It is very, very difficult not to allow this type of thing to affect your judgement of the quality of a piece of work, even if the marking criteria require you to exclude considerations of grammar. I note that Harish Kumar and Uwe Ziegenhagen correct this for the case in which you provide one copy per examiner.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With only `tikz` (don't forget to compile twice if things go wrong):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[draw,minimum width=4in,rotate=-45,fill=orange,text=blue,font=\LARGE] at ($(current page.north east) + (-0.9in,-0.9in)$) {Examiner's Copy};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \vspace*{2cm}
    \Large Thesis title
  \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

One possibility using the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package and its `firstpage` option; you can change the attributes (position, color, opacity, angle of the added text):

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[firstpage=true]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=2,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
color=red!70!black,
contents={\tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,font=\Huge] {Examiners Copy};},
vshift=2.5cm
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[firstpage=true]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=2,
angle=90,
opacity=1,
color=cyan!70!black,
contents={\tikz\node[draw,rounded corners,font=\sffamily\Huge,fill=orange!10] {Examiners Copy};},
vshift=2.5cm
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Although I like the other answers, just FYI, there is package called `draftwatermark` which allows you to put a background text.

- Use the global option `firstpage` if you'd like the mark to appear only on the first page.
- With `\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{1,1,0}` you could change the colour. Otherwise, in the grey scale, the option `\SetWatermarkLightness{0.7}` change the grey value.
- Change the scale of the mark with `\SetWatermarkScale{3}`
- And the text with `\SetWatermarkText{Examiners Copy}`

All together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
% Use the following to make modification
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{1,1,0}
\SetWatermarkAngle{45}
\SetWatermarkScale{3}
\SetWatermarkText{Examiners Copy}

\title{Lorem ipsum}
\author{O. Castillo-Felisola}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

It also works using the good old `eso-pic` package which I usually use to position arbitrary content on a page:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrreprt}

 \usepackage{eso-pic,rotating,graphicx}
 \usepackage{blindtext}

 \author{John Doe}
 \title{Some Thesis}

 \begin{document}

 \AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(200,200){\rotatebox{45}{\scalebox{3}{Examiner's copy}}}}
 \maketitle


 \blindtext

 \end{document}
```

[image: eso]