# Part of main text grabbed by watermark

Tags: listings, ntheorem, xwatermark

I am using the solution presented in [Q/A 132582](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/transparent-foreground-watermark/132584) to produce a transparent foreground watermark. With success most of the time. But on some rare occasions, a part of the main text is embedded into the watermark, as seen here

[image: Problem with watermark]

The text in black in the watermark should appear at the beginning of the first line of the next page instead. It is the title of a `ntheorem` theorem.

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer we now have a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark*[allpages,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{CORRIGÉ}
\usepackage{lipsum,listings}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
abc\\abc\\abc\\abc
\begin{lstlisting}
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{question}blblbabc\end{question}

\end{document}
```

This a MWE in the sense that if you abstain from using `ntheorem` or replace the `lstlisting` with a `verbatim`, the problem disappears.

Comment: How are you making the frames?

Comment: With the ``listings`` package's rounded frame feature. Other documents include frames made with ``mdframed``, but not this one.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly not an answer but a workaround, which may work for you if you are willing to load `tikz`. (The other package I am loading, `eso-pic`, gets loaded by the `xwatermark` package, so this is not an additional package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum,listings}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
\tikz[overlay]{\node[rotate=45,scale=6,text=gray!50] at (current page.center){CORRIG\'E};}}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
abc\\abc\\abc\\abc
\begin{lstlisting}
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{question}blblbabc\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]