# Read in multiple-page PDF and apply watermark to all pages

Tags: pdfpages, watermark, xwatermark

I would like to read in a multi-page pdf and then apply a watermark to all of the pages on it.

Here is the `LaTeX` script I'm using

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{pdfpages}  % Multi-page PDF inclusions

% Declare watermark
\newwatermark*[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{My Watermark}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{MultPageDocument.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The script above will read in all of the pages of the `PDF` document, however the watermark will **only** be applied to the **first page**.

How can I modify the scrip so that the watermark is applied to **all pages**?

Comment: You could use hooks to add a watermark, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132582/transparent-foreground-watermark/655529#655529

Comment: do not use the xwatermark package, it loads the catoptions package which is not fully compatible with a current latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{Confidential}
\SetWatermarkScale{4}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{pdffiles/061_00002.pdf}

\end{document}
```