# Blur the whole document and add a demo watermark on each page

Tags: fonts, watermark

This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/blur-the-text-so-its-not-readable) is about blurring text but it is not about blurring everything in the document. [This](http://texblog.org/2012/02/17/watermarks-draft-review-approved-confidential/) shows how to add the watermark over all pages (but it does not work with pictures, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118939/add-watermark-that-overlays-the-images) shows how to do it with some extra star over pictures).

**How can I blur the whole document and add a DEMO watermark on each page and possibly leave only one sentence without blurring?**

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "blurring". Should the letters be made fuzzy or out-of-focus looking, should they be rendered in gray instead of black, or maybe something else?

Comment: @Mico every page should be blurred: unreadable text, unreadable images, unreadable tables, unreadable figures, unreadable author entries, unreadable title page...except the large watermark on top of the whole text.

Comment: do you just need the text unreadable on paper or do you also want it to be not text in the pdf file?

Comment: Will there be math in the text that requires blurring, as well?

Comment: After contemplating this, maybe something totally different could be adequate (but I have no idea how to accomplish this): Replace all text in the output - except the part that shall remain readable -  with blind text ("lorem ipsum") in such a manner that tha paragraph shape is not affected; a good implementation of such a method might also use "blind math" for display formulas and "blind images" for illustrations ...

Answer (score 4):

Using Gonzalo's code with `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\waterbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\waterbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
 \fill[draw,white,opacity=0.7] ([shift={(2,2)}]current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
 \node[text width = 2in,rotate=-45] at ([shift={(10mm,10mm)}]current page.center) {Some text here that appeas dark and rest is blurred};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\newwatermark*[allpages,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{\usebox{\waterbox}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to adjust the position of text in

```
\node[text width = 2in,rotate=-45] at ([shift={(10mm,10mm)}]current page.center) {Some text here that appeas dark and rest is blurred};
```

Now with `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\waterbox}
\begin{lrbox}{\waterbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
 \fill[draw,white,opacity=0.7] ([shift={(2,2)}]current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
 \node[rotate=45,text width = 0.5\textwidth,scale=2,anchor=center,align=center] at ([shift={(0.6\paperwidth,1cm)}]current page.west) {Some text here that appeas dark and rest is blurred};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
\usebox{\waterbox}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This method will work with fully text documents only, but will break down for documents that include images and/or `\colorbox`es.

The macro `\blurpages{start page}{end page}{PDF file}` takes a complete unblurred document as its 3rd argument.

It builds successive blurry images for each page of the specified page range by stacking shifted images atop each other.  It then outputs the blurred page and continues through the page range.

In this MWE, I operate on the file xcolor.pdf, the documentation for the `xcolor` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,ifthen,xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{everypage}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}}
\newcommand\ateveryxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
%WATERMARK ON EVERY PAGE
\ateveryxy{.5\paperwidth}{.55\paperheight}{\makebox[0pt]{\scalebox{15}{DEMO}}}
%CONSTRUCT BLURRED IMAGE
\setstackgap{L}{.4pt}
\newcommand\blur[2][1]{%
  \Longstack{%
    \,\includegraphics[page=#1,width=\paperwidth]{#2}\\
    \,\,\,\includegraphics[page=#1,width=\paperwidth]{#2}\\
    \includegraphics[page=#1,width=\paperwidth]{#2}\\
    \,\,\includegraphics[page=#1,width=\paperwidth]{#2}\\
    \,\,\,\,\includegraphics[page=#1,width=\paperwidth]{#2}
  }%
}
%PLACE BLURRED IMAGES ON SUCCEEDING PAGES
\newcounter{blurpage}
\newcommand\blurpages[3]{%
  \setcounter{blurpage}{#1}%
  \whiledo{\value{blurpage}<#2}{%
    \atxy{0in}{\paperheight}{\blur[\value{blurpage}]{#3}}\ \clearpage%
    \stepcounter{blurpage}%
  }%
  \atxy{0in}{\paperheight}{\blur[\value{blurpage}]{#3}}\ \clearpage%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\blurpages{1}{9}{xcolor}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is where the method breaks down, however: if there are color filled regions, including both images and `\colorboxes`.

[image]