# Overlay all pages (alternative for watermark)

Tags: backgrounds, watermark

Hello I was wanting to put word in all pages exactly like the one shown

[Add watermark that overlays the images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118939/add-watermark-that-overlays-the-images)

Though the watermark works for me this one does not work for me (I ran the exact same code). Is there an alternative to write like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! You can use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` will add content to the `B`ack`G`round to all pages, while `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` will do the same but in the `F`ore`G`round (starred version will limit it to the current page).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageCenter{% At center of page
    \scalebox{10}{% Size (scaled 10x)
      \rotatebox{45}{% Angle
        \makebox[0pt]{% Centered horizontally
          \color{red!50}% Colour
          DRAFT%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Here's the same with `\AddToShipoutPictureFG`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!